# Log FFT of image doesn't make sense to me

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So I'm trying to understand the whole FFT transformation of an image using MatLab.
I do understand that initial image is in spatial domain where's the fft is in frequency or also known fourier domain.

Now my problem is, I cannot correlate the fft to the original image. Which part is the hat? Which part are the eyes?

I've been told that horizontal lines on fft represent vertical lines in original image, and vertical lines in fft represent the horizontal lines in the image.

Take these images as an example:

[image]

Comment: You may want to look into [Wavelets](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/index.html) if you are interested in the location of the edges. (see [Detecting Discontinuities and Breakdown Points](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/examples/detecting-discontinuities-and-breakdown-points.html) for an example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one area in the FFT that corresponds to the hat.  Broadly speaking, the center region of the FFT (low frequency components) provides intensity information and the outer regions (high frequency components) provide edge information.

Answer (score 1):

Well my understanding is that, to think about it simply, imagine the frequency as just that, the number of times something occurs, the FFT of an image is supposed to show just that, the number (concentration) in terms of one colour/intensity value.

Comment: The more you know... hahahah
Thanks, that makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: Thanks for the tidbit on the source of the lena image.  Hopefully the baboon image has a different origin.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this same experiment with some synthetic imagery of various periodic signals and see what happens:

```
[x y] = meshgrid(1:256);
im = (x<128);
F = fftshift(fft2(im));

subplot 211
imagesc(im);
subplot 212
imagesc(log(abs(F)))
```

Try

```
im = 1;
im = rem(x, 16) >= 8;
im = rem(y, 16) >= 8;
im = (rem(y, 16) >= 8) * (rem(x, 16) >= 8);
```